# Read custom headers in angular2

Tags: angular, http, .net-core

I have created .NET Core WebAPI and in each request I add custom header into response.

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Access-Token", newToken);
```

I also enbaled cors in server side:

```
app.UseCors(config =>   config.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
```

Every request in Augular2 side I am filtering and trying to get the "X-Access-Token" header but that returns null.

```
 getVehiclesReport(dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date, loaderName): Observable<IVehiclesReport> {
            return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "report/vehicles/" + this.getQueryDate(dateFrom) + "/" + this.getQueryDate(dateTo), this.jsonHeadersAuth)
            .map((response: Response) => this.mapResponse(response, response =><IVehiclesReport>response.json()))
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => this.ajaxService.push(loaderName));
    }


 protected mapResponse<TResult>(response: Response, func : Func<Response, TResult>): TResult {
        let token = response.headers.get("X-Access-Token");
        //returns null

        if(token && token != null && token != ''){
            this.localStorageService.setJwtToken(token);
        }

        return func(response);
    }
```

However I can see my X-Access-Token in Developer Options / Network / Response Headers.

Did somone faced that issue?

Comment: Can we see the block of code from response below?  Is the type or response an angular http?

Comment: are you using `HttpClient`?

Comment: @MurliPrajapati no its request from angular and I am using Http class built in angular2

Comment: @Chris response is instance of Response class from @angular/http

Comment: We need more information here, response has to be scoped to within your "filter" I assume? Can you update your question to contain the full code snippet doing the work? If you can see the token in dev tools, then its on the angular side.

Comment: Updated the code !

Comment: are you getting `response` in `mapResponse` method? I mean is it null or just headers are null.

Comment: nothing is null - header.get("X-Access-Token") returns null

Comment: Can you see `Access-Control-Allow-Headers : *` header in the networks tab?

Comment: I couldn't find the string values of header, but if you do this: let token = response.header.toJSON(); console.log(token); it should return a string of all headers, I would ensure the "X-Access-Token" is correct and it isn't something like "x-access-token" you can also do .keys() to get a list of keys.

Comment: look at this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957319/5271656

Comment: @David yes i do

Comment: @Chris toJSON() returns just content-type

Comment: @miechooy Can you modify your backend to explicitly expose the header X-Access-Token, instead of using wilcard * ?

Comment: @David still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone I just figured out. When I add my custom header I also need to add "Access-Control-Expose-Headers".

Soultion:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Access-Token", newToken);
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Access-Token");
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, please mark David as the answer king!