# How to read X-Total-Count from json-server in Angular http.get?

Tags: angular, json-server

I am using `json-server` at `localhost:3000`. it is working fine and I am able to get data in Angular `http.get`. I want to read response header `X-Total-Count`, inside angular .subscribe. But I can't see that property in the response header. But Chrome console shows that `X-Total-Count: 16`.

```js
this.catgoryItems.getAllServices(
    {
        _page: pageIndex || this.pageIndex,
        _limit: limit || this.limit
    })
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.dataSource = response.body;
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.alertService.showError('Error, plz try again later');
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read response headers from API response - Angular 5 + TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292270/angular-4-get-headers-from-api-response

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe response and access headers

```js
http
  .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Total-Count'));
  });
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184742/2742156

Answer (score 0):

you can get header using this

```js
request.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      let count = data.headers.getAll('x-total-count');
}
```