# Angular read HTTP header status

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a login page where I need to validate the student id and password to be matched from the database. I have the back-end API that sends validate the student account and sends response status when they are success or failed.

Here is my LoginComponent.ts

```
export class LoginComponent {

studentForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
private fb: FormBuilder,
private crudService: CrudService,
private router: Router) {
  this.studentForm = this.fb.group({
    id: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
  });
}
// This are the example for inserting data into database
saveStudentDetails(values) {
  const studentData = new FormData();

  studentData.append('id', values.id);
  studentData.append('password', values.password);
  this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    if (this.crudService.getData) {
    this.router.navigate(['address']); alert  ('"success"'); return; }
  });
}
}
```

// MY service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {

// Base api url
public url = 'http://localhost:8080/';
headerProperty: string;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

createUser(data) {
  return this.http.post(this.url + 'todo', data);
}

createAddress(data) {
  return this.http.post(this.url + 'address', data);
}

}
```

Ignore the saveStudentDetails, it just for testing purpose and my question is how can I make a validation base on response status from API and make it go to next page if the API send a success status.

// This is my backend api using slim framework

```
$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

$input = $request->getParsedBody();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= :id";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam("id", $input['id']);
$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetchObject();

// verify id.
if(!$user) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'No id found'], 404);  
}
// Compare the input password and the password from database for a validation
if (strcmp($input['password'],$user->password) == 1 ) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], 404);  
}

    return $this->response->withJson($input,202);
});
```

Comment: Can you show your backend code and what is the response you are getting back from there, and structure of the response object?

Comment: i already edit my code, check it out

Comment: Same as, in this post write angular http request like           this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe(resp => console.log(resp.headers)) 
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44292270/4834833

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass one more parameter to `POST` method as follows:

```js
const postHttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
};

postHttpOptions['observe'] = 'response';

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/'+ api_end_point, data, postHttpOptions)
.pipe(map(response => {
       return response;
  }));
```

As you can see, I have added `observe: 'response'`, which returns the full response with response headers.

Now you have access to response headers. You can do this:

```js
this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
  if (result.status === '202') {
    this.router.navigate(['address']); 
    alert('"success"'); 
    return; 
  }
});
```

**Update**

Use this function to send values to the API.

```js
    saveStudentDetails(values) {
      const studentData = {};

      studentData['id'] =  values.id;
      studentData['password'] =  values.password;
      this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
        this.student = result;
        console.log('status code ->' + result.status);
        this.router.navigate(['/address']);
      },
        err => {
          console.log('status code ->' + err.status);
          alert('"error"');
      });
    }

  }
```

Comment: loginstudent(data) {
        const postHttpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
          }),
          observe: 'response'
      };

      return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/' + 'login', data, postHttpOptions)
      .pipe(map(response => {
           return response;
        }));

  }

Comment: ill let u know later

Comment: Any idea why got error here https://imgur.com/gb0XUls on postHttpOptions?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But I have updated the answer a little bit. Please check it out. It should solve this error you are getting.

Comment: Just change `if condition` to `if (result.status === '202')`. It give desired output.

Comment: still the same error but now it is on the status, hmm something must be wrong here.

Comment: Use `result['status']` and you will see the status now

Comment: yeah its working now but i cannt login into. I have tried many others solution but when test the api on postman its working but when trying to use angular its return error 404. It must have a logic error in my logincomponent, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Can you create this scenario over stackblitz.com so that I can have a look on it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zznr1g ignore the interface, its on my logincomponent. Sorry my coding is a little bit messed up

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/hfvU3.png this is the error, when i test my backend in postman its working but when using angular its say no id found which my first if else statement from backend, you can refer my backend above

Comment: Thank you very much sir, its working already but its look like the if statement need to be changed because it does not read the result['status'] === '200' so i already edited you answer. Nice to meet you sir. Have a nice day

Comment: My pleasure! Have a great day :)