# How to get filename from response header content-disposition to download using Anulgar 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

I would like to get filename from my endpoint it's present on content-disposition but I don't know if there's a simple way to get that using JS/Angular. My endpoint returns a blob as file, and have this information in the header content-disposition

I'm using the method below to download file, since opening a new window usually is blocked by the browser

```
function saveFile(blob, filename) {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you share the code that gets the blob from the back-end? A service, i presume?

Comment: I am almost sure that the blob will no contain the name of the file unless the API is providing it on the request. Can you post a snapshot of the payload you are getting? Minus the blob content obviously. Use Postmanapp or devTools to get the snapshot.

Comment: The blob really does not have the filename, it is present only on the headers, at least in the chrome it ís in content-disposition

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus, I'm just calling the http get and using the blob of the response body, I suppose I  can get the file name from there, but how?

Comment: Are you using Angular's http client to get the blob from a URL? If so, you could easily get the headers from it. See csga5000's response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292270/angular-4-get-headers-from-api-response